# Create list of headings containing a tag in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, cross-reference, microsoft-word-365

I am trying to add tags under headings in my word document. I want to then use those tags to create a list of the headings that contain those tags. There will be enough headings and enough tags that doing this manually will be a tedious chore, and I would like the list to update automatically if possible.

The photo below shows what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image: Screenshot of desired result]

I tried using the index tool, but it seems like indexes can only output page numbers, which would not be useful to me. I tried to think through using cross references for this purpose, but I couldn't come up with anything that would be less effort than just typing it out manually.

I'm using Microsoft Word for Microsoft 365 MSO.

Comment: I have an extreme deep knowledge of Word, but no function comes to my mind that could solve that. Due to the headings I'm always lead to the StyleRef fields, but they alone won't cut it. However, this would be solvable via VBA. Find all Heading 1 styles and then add their heading content to a 2D array if the content between the heading and the following one contains your tag keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could certainly do this through VBA, but if you want to stick to fields:

- After each chapter title, add a SEQ field (with \h flag so it's hidden):

  {SEQ Chapter \h}
- Mark each Tag with an XE field (use index/mark)
- Create the index with the chapter number and a marker before the page number (you can't hide the page number):

  {Index \c "1" \s chapter  \e "    " \d " @@"}
- When you've finished your document, select all and press F9, then copy the index and paste as text:

> ```
> Tag1    1 @@1
> Tag2    1 @@1, 2 @@2, 3 @@3
> Tag3    3 @@3
> ```

- Now you can search/replace the page numbers in your index (use wildcards, replace @@[0-9]@ by nothing).

> ```
> Tag1    1  
> Tag2    1 , 2 , 3  
> Tag3    3
> ```